# SwiftUI UIViewRepresentable MKMapView With Selectable MKCircles loses selection when adding new Circle

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

I've been wrestling with getting SwiftUI working with MKMapView for a few days now. With the help of posts on here

[Accessing MKMapView elements as UIViewRepresentable in the main (ContentView) SwiftUI view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56563660/accessing-mkmapview-elements-as-uiviewrepresentable-in-the-main-contentview-sw)

and articles like this online

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/advanced-mkmapview-with-swiftui

I've managed to get something working. Taps select placed circles and hilights them in blue when selected. The problem I'm encountering however is that the selected circle is lost whenever I add a new circle to my array of circles.

[image: Example App Screenshot]

I've uploaded a test app zip for this [here](http://jimtreats.com/tests/SwiftUIMapKitTest.zip) (*Apologies for the code, my Swift knowledge is rusty and my SwiftUI and MapKit even more so*)

The app has the following structure

- ContentView

  - The main SwiftUI view containing my MapView in a zstack with some buttons
  - including the following @States

    - @State private var circleRegions = MKCircle
    - @State private var selectedCircleIndex : Int?
    - @State private var selectedCircle : MKCircle? = nil
- MapView

  - The UIViewRepresentable that wraps the MKMapView, and has a Coordinator to handle MKMapView callbacks
  - including the following @Bindings up to the main ContentView state variables

    - @Binding var circleRegions : [MKCircle]
    - @Binding var selectedCircleIndex : Int?
    - @Binding var selectedCircle : MKCircle?
- Coordinator

  - A coordinator that has the MapView as it's parent property and implements required MKMapViewDelegate methods including our mapTapped method

When MapView calls its MakeUIView() it creates the MKMapView and sets up the Coordinator as that maps delegate and adds a tap gesture recognizer as follows

```
    mapView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: context.coordinator, action: #selector(context.coordinator.mapTapped(_:))))
```

This mapTapped handling goes immediately up to its MapView parent to handle the tap.

Once the tap is processed into world space I check it against the circleRegions array @Binding property to determine if a region selection was changed. I then update the selectedCircleIndex and selectedCircle @Binding properties to reflect the selection and then I force rebuild the MKMapView's overlays to ensure that I get to create new renderers for those overlays at which point I can update the colour of the renderers to reflect the selection.

This all works fine although the overlays do blink as they're removed and re-added but not the end of the world, I couldn't find a better way of updating the renderer colour beyond removing and re-adding all the overlays.

The issue is that if I select a circle making it blue and then scroll the map a little to then press the circle button to create a new circle in another place then I'm left with both circles displaying as red with the last selected one that should be blue still "selected" (the selected circle and index are correct) but incorrectly displaying as red.

Debugging this it seems that the MapView's circleRegions array @Binding property becomes invalidly empty during the Coordinator's mapView(:rendererFor) MKMapViewDelegate call. Which stops my code from matching an index of the circle against the parent's circleRegions. Even more confusing is the fact that if you put a breakpoint at this point in code, you can go up the stack to when the parent MapView was handleTap()-ing and calling rebuildOverlays(). At this point its circleRegions are correct, yet by the time we hit the renderer callback they're invalid.

Swift makes it hard to see that the Coordinator's parent MapView is the same instance at these different places in the call stack as you can't easily look at pointer values of the MapView self or Coordinator parent at the different times.

To try and debug or fix this issue I've added a couple of extra config lets that change the behaviour

- MapView

  - let dispatchMapViewUpdates = false

    - which controls whether the rebuildOverlays() happening within the tap gesture recogniser callback is done immediately or dispatched back onto the main queue
- Coordinator

  - let testWithIndex = true // update this to test with index or optional circle
  - which controls whether the map renderer delegate method uses the selected index or a selected MKCircle? on the parent to tell if the circle being rendered is selected or not

Sadly none of these options fix the issue which just leaves me baffled as to what is going on. I've also confirmed that this issue occurs on device the same as in the simulator so its not a Simulator only SwiftUI issue.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd certainly appreciate it. Cheers